# Searching numbers in line with different lengths

Tags: python, numbers, line

I got gps log files with line of text

```
{"location": {"lat": 50.0918805, "lng": 14.4261817}, "accuracy": 29.1671027, "ts": 1598515548}
```

My goal is to print values of latitude and longtitude, I was able to do this:

```
folder_path = 'D:\path'
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(folder_path, '*.geo.json')):
  with open(filename, 'r') as filecontent:
    readme = filecontent.read()
    lat = readme[21:28]
    long = readme[40:47]
    print(lat, long)
```

And I tought it was perfect for me, I got nice numbers like:

```
50.0918 14.4260
50.0920 4.42629
50.0918 14.4260
50.0917 14.4258
50.0920 14.4263
50.0917 14.4259
50.0918 14.4260
50.0919 4261233
```

But there is actualy numbers missing, the problem is in logs, the numbers generated for latitude/longtitude is not always same length and I print numbers from position of first character.
I tried to print only numbers and split them by "," but there are more numbers I dont want there.

And here I am stucked, cant figure out how to print all numbers after `"lat":` and `"lng":` but not after `"accuracy":`

If you could help me it would make me happy, cheers.

Comment: use json library, then you can treat your file as a dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) library to parse your `.json` files:

```py
import json
import glob

folder_path = 'D:\path'
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(folder_path, '*.geo.json')):
    coords = json.load(open(filename, 'r'))
    print(
        coords['location']['lat'],
        coords['location']['lng'],
        coords['accuracy']
    )

# 50.0918805 14.4261817 29.1671027
```

Answer (score 0):

This is structured text, so you might as well make use of the structure, e.g.:

```
import json

content = """{"location": {"lat": 50.0918805, "lng": 14.4261817}, "accuracy": 29.1671027, "ts": 1598515548}"""
data = json.loads(content)
print(data["location"]["lat"], data["location"]["lng"])
```

This yields

```
50.0918805 14.4261817
```